# Remove extra white spaces in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I tried to write a script that removes extra white spaces but I didn't manage to finish it.

Basically I want to transform `abc  sssd g g sdg    gg  gf` into `abc sssd g g sdg gg gf`.

In languages like PHP or C#, it would be very easy, but not in C++, I see. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

char* trim3(char* s) {
    int l = strlen(s);

    while(isspace(s[l - 1])) --l;
    while(* s && isspace(* s)) ++s, --l;

    return strndup(s, l);
}

char *str_replace(char * t1, char * t2, char * t6)
{
    char*t4;
    char*t5=(char *)malloc(10);
    memset(t5, 0, 10);
    while(strstr(t6,t1))
    {
        t4=strstr(t6,t1);
        strncpy(t5+strlen(t5),t6,t4-t6);
        strcat(t5,t2);
        t4+=strlen(t1);
        t6=t4;
    }

    return strcat(t5,t4);
}

void remove_extra_whitespaces(char* input,char* output)
{
    char* inputPtr = input; // init inputPtr always at the last moment.
    int spacecount = 0;
    while(*inputPtr != '\0')
    {
        char* substr;
        strncpy(substr, inputPtr+0, 1);

        if(substr == " ")
        {
            spacecount++;
        }
        else
        {
            spacecount = 0;
        }

        printf("[%p] -> %d\n",*substr,spacecount);

        // Assume the string last with \0
        // some code
        inputPtr++; // After "some code" (instead of what you wrote).
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("testing 2 ..\n");

    char input[0x255] = "asfa sas    f f dgdgd  dg   ggg";
    char output[0x255] = "NO_OUTPUT_YET";
    remove_extra_whitespaces(input,output);

    return 1;
}
```

It doesn't work. I tried several methods. What I am trying to do is to iterate the string letter by letter and dump it in another string as long as there is only one space in a row; if there are two spaces, don't write the second character to the new string.

How can I solve this?

Comment: it is c++, this is how i compile an run `clear; rm -f test2.exe; g++ -o test2.exe test2.cpp; ./test2.exe;`

Comment: Don't code C-style in C++! Use the language features.

Comment: First, the code is actually C, not C++ even though you compile it as such. Second, your `substr` points to a random place in memory since you don't initialize it and you're causing *undefined behaviour*. You can get a character out of a c string just by indexing it, so there is no need for `strncpy`. Your thinking is also correct, you just have to implement the copying part to another string.

Comment: @Damian You should provide more diagnostics than "It dosen't work". Please specify an example input, the output for that example, and expected output. Or, if it crashes, when and how does it crash?

Comment: @Olaf There are valid reasons to code C-style in C++. Most of the time, a more idiomatically and distinctly C++ alternative might be better, but that's on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Still semantics can differ. Even for identical syntax.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm missing the significance of the fact that C and C++ might accept the same code with slightly different semantics in this context?

Comment: yes, i agree, but i consider it `c++`, since i compile it with `g++` and when i want to find something i search for `c++` on google, hope i am right

Comment: @Damian: You are right. You just should not add C tag for C++ questions. My comment was just you should use a more C++-ish coding style and utilise the features that language provides.

Comment: Hm... `0x255`... A very *curious* constant.

Comment: `This is my code: … It doesn't work.` You present uncommented code with abysmally named variables, sprinkled with magic literals. With this lot of string functions, I'd code a variant or two just using char pointers to compare which I like better, and why. Once this is readable and works, you could present it over at code review.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple, non-C++11 solution, using the same `remove_extra_whitespace()` signature as in the question:

```
#include <cstdio>

void remove_extra_whitespaces(char* input, char* output)
{
    int inputIndex = 0;
    int outputIndex = 0;
    while(input[inputIndex] != '\0')
    {
        output[outputIndex] = input[inputIndex];

        if(input[inputIndex] == ' ')
        {
            while(input[inputIndex + 1] == ' ')
            {
                // skip over any extra spaces
                inputIndex++;
            }
        }

        outputIndex++;
        inputIndex++;
    }

    // null-terminate output
    output[outputIndex] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char input[0x255] = "asfa sas    f f dgdgd  dg   ggg";
    char output[0x255] = "NO_OUTPUT_YET";
    remove_extra_whitespaces(input,output);

    printf("input: %s\noutput: %s\n", input, output);

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
input: asfa sas    f f dgdgd  dg   ggg
output: asfa sas f f dgdgd dg ggg
```

Comment: No problem. Note also that `remove_extra_whitespaces()` assumes that the final string won't overflow the memory allocated for `output`; if it does, you'd likely get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 30):

There are already plenty of nice solutions.  I propose you an alternative based on a dedicated `<algorithm>` meant to avoid consecutive duplicates:  **[`unique_copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique_copy/)**:

```
void remove_extra_whitespaces(const string &input, string &output)
{
    output.clear();  // unless you want to add at the end of existing sring...
    unique_copy (input.begin(), input.end(), back_insert_iterator<string>(output),
                                     [](char a,char b){ return isspace(a) && isspace(b);});  
    cout << output<<endl; 
}
```

Here is a **[live demo](http://ideone.com/qD0hNW)**.  *Note that I changed from c style strings to the safer and more powerful C++ strings.*

***Edit:*** if keeping c-style strings is required in your code, you could use almost the same code but with pointers instead of iterators.  That's the magic of C++.  Here is [another live demo](http://ideone.com/qmLpR0).

Comment: That's a nice one. Though it should have the original's signature, probably.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes,  I edited to recommend switching to `std::string`

Comment: yes, i agree as well, string is the best, but all the `script` is written (2000 lines) using `char*` ... and this script must run on `centos 4, 5.1` , `debian 4`, `unix based systems` ... and so on, and it is better to use the simplest functions possible, to not get `segmentation fault` ...

Comment: Your function doesn't work properly. If there's spaces in the beggining or the end, it keeps them. Not what the op wants.

Comment: @José my function removes redundant spaces as requested by the OP.  I couldn't find any evidence in the question that the starting space or the ending space should be removed.   If this would be a requirement, you'd just replace `input.begin()` with a `find_if()` and add a conditional erase before returning.

Comment: @Damian the nice thing with the algorithm library is that many algorithms also work with pointers instead of iterators.  Here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/qmLpR0) using the same algorithm , yet keeping c-style strings as you like them ;-)

Comment: Just two general comments: 1. `using namespace` is a scourge, only acceptable when the namespace is guaranteed to only contain the symbols you want to import. 2. `std::endl` does a manual flush, which is generally simply wateful.

Comment: BTW: You might want to add the cstring-solution to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since you use C++, you can take advantage of standard-library features designed for that sort of work. You could use `std::string` (instead of `char[0x255]`) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), which will replace most of the pointer arithmetic.

First, make a string stream:

```
std::istringstream stream(input);
```

Then, read strings from it. It will remove the whitespace delimiters automatically:

```
std::string word;
while (stream >> word)
{
    ...
}
```

Inside the loop, build your output string:

```
    if (!output.empty()) // special case: no space before first word
        output += ' ';
    output += word;
```

A disadvantage of this method is that it allocates memory dynamically (including  several reallocations, performed when the output string grows).

Comment: yes, `string` > `char[0x255]` , i agree, but i want to stick with `char*` because all the code is in `char*` ...

Comment: You can convert back and forth - from `char*` to `string` by a constructor, and back by `c_str()` and `strcpy`. Lots of unnecessary work for the CPU, but less headache for you.

Comment: @anatolyg: If it's done at the right places at the right times, there's probably at most a little amount of extra-work for the optimizer.

Comment: yes, i agree as well, string is the best, but all the `script` is written (2000 lines) using `char*` ... and this script must run on `centos 4, 5.1` , `debian 4`, `unix based systems` ... and so on, and it is better to use the simplest functions possible, to not get `segmentation fault` ...

Comment: @Damian: using simpler functions is no guarantee of avoiding bugs.  The more code you have to write yourself, instead of using library tools, the more chance there is of having a bug.  Obviously you have to understand the library functions you use, and C++ has way more than C.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) which reduces adjacent duplicates to a single instance according to how you define what makes two elements equal is.

Here I have defined elements as equal if they are both *whitespace* characters:

```
inline std::string& remove_extra_ws_mute(std::string& s)
{
    s.erase(std::unique(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b){
        return std::isspace(a) && std::isspace(b);
    }), std::end(s));

    return s;
}

inline std::string remove_extra_ws_copy(std::string s)
{
    return remove_extra_ws_mute(s);
}
```

[std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) moves the duplicates to the end of the string and returns an iterator to the beginning of them so they can be erased.

Additionally, if you **must** work with low level strings then you can still use [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) on the pointers:

```
char* remove_extra_ws(char const* s)
{
    std::size_t len = std::strlen(s);

    char* buf = new char[len + 1];
    std::strcpy(buf, s);

    // Note that std::unique will also retain the null terminator
    // in its correct position at the end of the valid portion
    // of the string    
    std::unique(buf, buf + len + 1, [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b){
        return (a && std::isspace(a)) && (b && std::isspace(b));
    });

    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways of doing this (e.g., using regular expressions), but one way you could do this is using [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a stateful functor remembering whether the last character was a space:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct if_not_prev_space
{
    // Is last encountered character space.
    bool m_is = false;

    bool operator()(const char c)
    {                                      
        // Copy if last was not space, or current is not space.                                                                                                                                                              
        const bool ret = !m_is || c != ' ';
        m_is = c == ' ';
        return ret;
    }
};


int main()
{
    const std::string s("abc  sssd g g sdg    gg  gf into abc sssd g g sdg gg gf");
    std::string o;
    std::copy_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::back_inserter(o), if_not_prev_space());
    std::cout << o << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: yes, `string` > `char[0x255]` , i agree, but i want to stick with `char*` because all the code is in `char*` ... , can it be done?

Comment: Not sure you meant to address the comment to me, but see [`string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Comment: this leaves one extra space at the end of the string if it ends in whitespace. Not sure if OP's shifting requirements need that to be taken care of...

Comment: @jaggedSpire Good point. I must say I thought of that, and decided (perhaps wishfull-thinkingly) that it fits the problem requirements. If not, though, it can be solved with a single line after the application of `copy_if`.

Comment: yes, i agree as well, string is the best, but all the `script` is written (2000 lines) using `char*` ... and this script must run on `centos 4, 5.1` , `debian 4`, `unix based systems` ... and so on, and it is better to use the simplest functions possible, to not get `segmentation fault` ...

Comment: This is an elegant solution (stateful predicate).

Comment: C is a very old programming language, it gives me headaches all the time ... look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873677/segmentation-fault-on-malloc-function

Answer (score 3):

for in-place modification you can apply erase-remove technic:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string input {"asfa sas    f f dgdgd  dg   ggg"};
    bool prev_is_space = true;
    input.erase(std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [&prev_is_space](unsigned char curr) {
        bool r = std::isspace(curr) && prev_is_space;
        prev_is_space = std::isspace(curr);
        return r;

    }), input.end());

    std::cout << input << "\n";
}
```

So you first move all extra spaces to the end of the string and then truncate it.

---

The great advantage of C++ is that is universal enough to port your code to plain-c-static strings with only *few* modifications:

```
void erase(char * p) {
    // note that this ony works good when initial array is allocated in the static array
    // so we do not need to rearrange memory
    *p = 0; 
}

int main()
{
    char input [] {"asfa sas    f f dgdgd  dg   ggg"};
    bool prev_is_space = true;
    erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(input), std::end(input), [&prev_is_space](unsigned char curr) {
        bool r = std::isspace(curr) && prev_is_space;
        prev_is_space = std::isspace(curr);
        return r;

    }));

    std::cout << input << "\n";
}
```

Interesting enough `remove` step here is string-representation independent. It will work with `std::string` without modifications at all.

Comment: yes, `string` > `char[0x255]` , i agree, but i want to stick with `char*` because all the code is in `char*` ...

Comment: Nice, but the static `prev_is_space` would not be reset if you would execute this bloc several times (in a loop or in a function or in several threads).  For this to work safely you'd need to capture a local bool that you can reset when needed.

Comment: @Christophe, I see. Thanks.

Comment: yes, i agree as well, string is the best, but all the `script` is written (2000 lines) using `char*` ... and this script must run on `centos 4, 5.1` , `debian 4`, `unix based systems` ... and so on, and it is better to use the simplest functions possible, to not get `segmentation fault` ...

Answer (score 2):

I have the sinking feeling that good ol'  scanf will do (in fact, this is the C school equivalent to Anatoly's C++ solution):

```
void remove_extra_whitespaces(char* input, char* output)
{
    int srcOffs = 0, destOffs = 0, numRead = 0;

    while(sscanf(input + srcOffs, "%s%n", output + destOffs, &numRead) > 0)
    {
        srcOffs += numRead;
        destOffs += strlen(output + destOffs);
        output[destOffs++] = ' '; // overwrite 0, advance past that
    }
    output[destOffs > 0 ? destOffs-1 : 0] = '\0';
}
```

We exploit the fact that `scanf` has magical built-in space skipping capabilities. We then use the perhaps less known `%n` "conversion" specification which gives us the amount of chars consumed by `scanf`. This feature frequently comes in handy when reading from strings, like here. The bitter drop which makes this solution less-than-perfect is the `strlen` call on the output (there is no "how many bytes have I actually just *written*" conversion specifier, unfortunately).

Last not least use of scanf is easy here because sufficient memory is guaranteed to exist at `output`; if that were not the case, the code would become more complex due to buffering and overflow handling.

Comment: `sscanf` is a function that ca be used in `ANSI C (plain C)` as well?

Comment: @Damian Oh yes, it is. It's part of the C standard (and with it, part of the POSIX standard for Unix-like systems).

Comment: thank you, you know, C is a very old programming language, it gives me headaches all the time ... look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873677/segmentation-fault-on-malloc-function

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing c-style, here's a way to do what you want.
Note that you can remove `'\r'` and `'\n'`  which are line breaks (but of course that's up to you if you consider those whitespaces or not).

This function should be as fast or faster than any other alternative and no memory allocation takes place even when it's called with std::strings (I've overloaded it).

```
char temp[] = " alsdasdl   gasdasd  ee";
remove_whitesaces(temp);
printf("%s\n", temp);

int remove_whitesaces(char *p)
{
    int len = strlen(p);
    int new_len = 0;
    bool space = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        switch (p[i])
        {
        case ' ': space = true;  break;
        case '\t': space = true;  break;
        case '\n': break; // you could set space true for \r and \n
        case '\r': break; // if you consider them spaces, I just ignore them.
        default:
            if (space && new_len > 0)
                p[new_len++] = ' ';
            p[new_len++] = p[i];
            space = false;
        }
    }

    p[new_len] = '\0';

    return new_len;
}

// and you can use it with strings too,

inline int remove_whitesaces(std::string &str)
{
    int len = remove_whitesaces(&str[0]);
    str.resize(len);
    return len; // returning len for consistency with the primary function
                // but u can return std::string instead.
}

// again no memory allocation is gonna take place,
// since resize does not not free memory because the length is either equal or lower
```

If you take a brief look at the C++ Standard library, you will notice that a lot C++ functions that return std::string, or other std::objects are basically a wrapper to a well written extern "C" function. So don't be afraid to use C functions in C++ applications, if they are well written and you can overload them to support std::strings and such.

For example, in Visual Studio 2015, `std::to_string` is written exactly like this:

```
inline string to_string(int _Val)
    {   // convert int to string
    return (_Integral_to_string("%d", _Val));
    }

inline string to_string(unsigned int _Val)
    {   // convert unsigned int to string
    return (_Integral_to_string("%u", _Val));
    }
```

and _Integral_to_string is a wrapper to a C function sprintf_s

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    string _Integral_to_string(const char *_Fmt, _Ty _Val)
    {   // convert _Ty to string
    static_assert(is_integral<_Ty>::value,
        "_Ty must be integral");
    char _Buf[_TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE];
    int _Len = _CSTD sprintf_s(_Buf, _TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE, _Fmt, _Val);
    return (string(_Buf, _Len));
    }
```

Comment: hmm, very intresting, so basically your `int remove_whitesaces(char *p)` function, does not have to take two parameters, just modify it "on the fly" with the power of pointers, right?

Comment: Yeah, because the output length will always be equal or lower than the input length, so there's no need to create another object. I also overloaded it to support std::strings (and again no memory allocation takes place). I thought you would accept my answer since it's actually customizable (and doesn't accept tabs ('\t') which are considered spaces by almost everyone. And it can ignore line breaks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a longish(but easy) solution that does not use pointers.
It can be optimized further but hey it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void removeExtraSpace(string str);
int main(){
    string s;
    cout << "Enter a string with extra spaces: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    removeExtraSpace(s);
    return 0;
}
void removeExtraSpace(string str){
    int len = str.size();
    if(len==0){
        cout << "Simplified String: " << endl;
        cout << "I would appreciate it if you could enter more than 0 characters. " << endl;
        return;
    }
    char ch1[len];
    char ch2[len];
    //Placing characters of str in ch1[]
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        ch1[i]=str[i];
    }
    //Computing index of 1st non-space character
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(ch1[i] != ' '){
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    int cons_arr = 1;
    ch2[0] = ch1[pos];
    for(int i=(pos+1); i<len; i++){
        char x = ch1[i];
        if(x==char(32)){
            //Checking whether character at ch2[i]==' '
            if(ch2[cons_arr-1] == ' '){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                ch2[cons_arr] = ' ';
                cons_arr++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        ch2[cons_arr] = x;
        cons_arr++;
    }
    //Printing the char array
    cout << "Simplified string: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<cons_arr; i++){
        cout << ch2[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but this is how I did it on my homework. The only case where it might break a bit is when there is spaces at the beginning of the string EX "   wor   ds " In that case, it will change it to " wor ds"

```
void ShortenSpace(string &usrStr){
   char cha1;
   char cha2;
   for (int i = 0; i < usrStr.size() - 1; ++i) {
      cha1 = usrStr.at(i);
      cha2 = usrStr.at(i + 1);
      
      if ((cha1 == ' ') && (cha2 == ' ')) {
         usrStr.erase(usrStr.begin() + 1 + i);
         --i;//edit: was ++i instead of --i, made code not work properly
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up here for a slighly different problem. Since I don't know where else to put it, and I found out what was wrong, I share it here. Don't be cross with me, please.
I had some strings that would print additional spaces at their ends, while showing up without spaces in debugging. The strings where formed in windows calls like VerQueryValue(), which besides other stuff outputs a string length, as e.g. iProductNameLen in the following line converting the result to a string named strProductName:

```
    strProductName = string((LPCSTR)pvProductName, iProductNameLen)
```

then produced a string with a \0 byte at the end, which did not show easily in de debugger, but printed on screen as a space. I'll leave the solution of this as an excercise, since it is not hard at all, once you are aware of this.