# Segmentation fault on malloc function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a script that connects on one of my 10 servers trough **SSH** (`libssh2`). The program uses `fork` as a threading system. It is entering the server, executes a command (like `free -m` or check the CPU USSAGE), and sends the output trough a **HTTP REQUEST** to another server.

It works just fine, but from time to time it is not sending data back to the HTTP SERVER. I done a little debug with `puts('DEBUG123 ...')` to see where it is crashing. I do this because i use `FORK` and i am unable to see where it is crasing. Down there you see the code.

```
... code from the fork
puts("DEBUG 6");
sprintf(param,"%s%s",param,my_encode(info));
puts("DEBUG 6.5");
getContent(MY_HOST,HOST_IP,param);
puts("DEBUG 7");
... code from the fork
```

code of the my_encode functions that encrypts my data before sending it to the **HTTP SERVER** :

```
char *my_encode(char* bytes_to_encode)
{
    puts("S-DEBUG 1");
    int in_len = strlen(bytes_to_encode);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.1");
    char buf[5200];
    char *res = (char *)malloc(3600);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.2");
    memset(buf,0,1200);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.3");
    memset(res,0,3600);
    puts("S-DEBUG 2");

    strcpy(buf,base64_encode(bytes_to_encode,in_len));

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(buf);i++)
    {
        strcat(res,switch_encode(buf[i]));
    }
    puts("S-DEBUG 3");
    return res;

}
```

This is the output that i am getting :

```
Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1
S-DEBUG 1.2
S-DEBUG 1.3
S-DEBUG 2
S-DEBUG 3
DEBUG 6.5
DEBUG 7
DEBUG 1
-- SUCCESSFUL SEND

Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1
S-DEBUG 1.2
S-DEBUG 1.3
S-DEBUG 2
S-DEBUG 3
DEBUG 6.5
DEBUG 7
DEBUG 1
-- SUCCESSFUL SEND

Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1
S-DEBUG 1.2
S-DEBUG 1.3
S-DEBUG 2
S-DEBUG 3
DEBUG 6.5
DEBUG 7
DEBUG 1
-- SUCCESSFUL SEND

Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1 <--- HERE IT IS CRASHING
DEBUG 1
-- ERROR ON SEND

Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1
S-DEBUG 1.2
S-DEBUG 1.3
S-DEBUG 2
S-DEBUG 3
DEBUG 6.5
DEBUG 7
-- SUCCESSFUL SEND

Linux -> username password 1.2.3.4 22
DEBUG 2
DEBUG 3
DEBUG 4
DEBUG 5
DEBUG 6
S-DEBUG 1
S-DEBUG 1.1 <--- HERE IT IS CRASHING
DEBUG 1
-- ERROR ON SEND
```

So for my understanding, it is crashing at the `malloc` funtion here :

```
char *res = (char *)malloc(3600);
```

And this is a basic message that i send :

```
username:password:1.2.3.4:22:Linux:Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8200 @ 2.77GHz:242 238 3 0 15 64:no_server_load]
```

Sometimes it is crashing on it.

Also i have changed the line `char *res = (char *)malloc(3600);` , originally it was `char *res = (char *)malloc(1200);`. I believed that i don't have enough memory space.

1. Where is the problem?
2. Do i need to rewrite the `my_encode` function so it will no longer crash? If so, how??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get a coredump? We can only guess without it.

Comment: Your `for` loop with `strcat(res,switch_encode(buf[i]));` in it looks *very* wrong. I suspect you're corrupting your heap, which is why `malloc` subsequently fails.

Comment: @YSC it is C++, even though it looks like C ... i mean i compile it using `g++` , and how can i do a core dump? Keep in mind that this is happening after the forking, god knows what is happening, i cannot see it ...

Comment: are you sure you are freeing `char *res`... if you are using c++ you should use <string>

Comment: @PaulR please explain, i don't quite understand, but the bug is at `char *res = (char *)malloc(3600);` line, the last `puts` is `S-DEBUG 1.1` , dosen't reach `S-DEBUG 1.2`, understand?

Comment: Windows or Unix-like/BSD-like?

Comment: @lmiguelmh  i bvelieve not ... `char* res` must free itself after the return in that function, right?

Comment: @YSC , LINUX (alt sorts, from Centos 4-7 to UBUNTU 8 ... 15, to DEBIAN 4 ... 8), i mean, that is why it is written in `C++`, to be compatible, thus i would use `C#` if i could, hope you unterstand me

Comment: @Damian absolutely not. you need to free it yourself.

Comment: Type the following command before calling your application: `ulimit -c unlimited`. You'll get a coredump as soon as it crashes and you can analize it with `gdb <application-binary> <coredump>`. Be sure to compile with the debug informations (`-g`).

Comment: @YSC, app is not crashing, the fork of the app is crashing, it could go up to 20 logins, 10 sendints, 10 error or send, understand? also i don't have `gdb`, it is the only way?

Comment: If you use any kind of optimisation enabled, you cannot be sure that output and maloc call are not reordered or optimised.

Comment: Funny observation: call to malloc followed by memset is often replaced by calloc by GCC

Comment: what would be the recommended solution?

Comment: Funny that nobody has mentioned it before: You are not checking the *malloc()* return value. If you did, you would most probably have observed it being NULL (because you apparently fail to free it). And the crash is most probably not in the *malloc()* itself, but rather when your program tries to access memory at the NULL pointer.

Comment: what to do in order to prevent that ? free memory? i already tried, see here http://pastebin.com/0YFJtyEt ... still crashing

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this (free your buffer):

```
#include <string>
void my_encode(char* bytes_to_encode, std::string& encoded) {
    puts("S-DEBUG 1");
    int in_len = strlen(bytes_to_encode);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.1");
    char buf[5200];
    char *res = (char *)malloc(3600);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.2");
    memset(buf,0,1200);
    puts("S-DEBUG 1.3");
    memset(res,0,3600);
    puts("S-DEBUG 2");

    strcpy(buf,base64_encode(bytes_to_encode,in_len));

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(buf);i++)
    {
        strcat(res,switch_encode(buf[i]));
    }
    puts("S-DEBUG 3");

    encoded = res;
    free(res);
}

void main() {
    char *s = new char[32];
    strcpy(s, "hello");
    std::string str;
    my_encode (s, str);
    const char* result = str.c_str();
}
```

Comment: thanks, for the help, really need `std::string& encoded` ? can't i just live it `char *my_encode(char* bytes_to_encode)` ? The thing is that i am well aware that i should use `string` instead of `char*` or `char[100]` ... but i don't want to rewrite 3000 lines where everywhere is used `char*` ...

Comment: yep that is the safest way... but there are other possibilities too like returning the string (but the string will be copied everytime)

Comment: // ssh2connect.cpp:621: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer ERROR WITH `char info2[3000] = ...`
  
  // ssh2connect.cpp:621: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ ERROR WITH `char* info2 = ...`  CODE : http://pastebin.com/GTfbpXq9

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should run fine now. btw if you need the result to be a `char*` and not a `const char*` you will need to use `strcpy` again

Comment: the first 2 lines of `main` should be removed, you can just use `"hello"` directly as the argument (and the function should accept `char const *`)

Comment: i don't need this fixed variable "hello", i don't need this `strcpy(s, "hello");` because i generate the info value like this : http://pastebin.com/MsyQw2Bp so my code should look like this : http://pastebin.com/iLThgSNS (still gives error), i believe there is an overflow somewhere, after the `malloc` ...

Comment: @Damian the general idea is to use references (string&) and avoid the use of pointers (malloc or new). Again you should clean/rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf(param,"%s%s",param,my_encode(info));` is an error. The input and output cannot overlap for sprintf, this causes undefined behaviour.

You probably meant `strcat(param, my_encode(info));` although it would be better to include a buffer size check.

Your code suffers from not including any method of preventing buffer overflows.  There could be overflows happening but you don't know where.  This may or may not be causing your problem, you have no way of telling. Even if there isn't, then changing the input may cause one.

This is a poor way to code and your life will be difficult trying to debug it.  My advice would be to rewrite all of this code to include strict checking of buffer sizes and ensure that you never read or write past the end of a buffer.  In C++ the easiest way to do this is to use resizeable containers.

Comment: i agree with you, it will be the right way to rewrite the program, but i don't want to rewrite 5000 lines of code, i just want to solve this and move on to other projects ... so your ideea is to change `sprintf(param,"%s%s",param,my_encode(info));` to `strcat(param, my_encode(info));` ? I must tell you, believe me, the error comes from the `my_encode` function, i have tested and re-tested it ...

Comment: @Damian this is one error, there may or may not be others

Comment: Nobody can tell just based on the code you posted whether or not you cause buffer overflows, but it is a likely problem based on what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `C++` - use `std::string` to manage memory and avoid allocation/deallocation problems.

```
//get base64.cpp and base64.h 
//from here http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html
#include <base64.h>

std::string my_encode(const std::string& bytes_to_encode)
{
    puts("S-DEBUG 1");
    std::string output = base64_encode(bytes_to_encode.c_str(),bytes_to_encode.length());
    puts("S-DEBUG 2");
    return output;
}
```