# Removing all but one whitespace between words in C++

Tags: c++

I need to remove all but one white space between the words. I go through the string and `if (temp.back() == ' ' && c != ' ')` I check for the last space before we come onto the next word. But it removes all of the white spaces. Any hint where the problem is?

```
string removeWhiteSpace(string current)
{
  string myNewString = "";
  string temp = "";
  for (char c : current)
  {
    temp.push_back(c);
    if (temp.back() == ' ' && c != ' ')
    {
      myNewString.push_back(' ');
    }
    if (c != ' ')
    {
      myNewString.push_back(c);
    }
  }
  return myNewString;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove extra white spaces in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301432/remove-extra-white-spaces-in-c)

Comment: First of all, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), that's how you usually solve this kind of problems.

Comment: As for alternative solutions, you could use string streams and stream iterators to get "words" that you append to a new string with only a single space in between.

Comment: On trick that may help would be to find the index location of the first white space and keep a temp of that, then remove all white space between that and the next non white space character. After you have removed the white space then use that temp index value to add back a single white space at that location. This may not be the most efficient way, but it would solve your problem. Also if there are more than one sections of white spaces you can update the temp index location for the next set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the conditional

```
if (temp.back() == ' ' && c != ' ')
```

you want to add the space if last character is NOT a space and `c` is a space:

```
if (temp.back() != ' ' && c == ' ')
```

(you reversed `==` and `!=` operators).

Also you need to push the new character `c` AFTER this conditional block (otherwise `temp.back()` and `c` will always be the same character).

Finally at the beginning the string `temp` is empty, calling `back()` is not allowed, you should initialize it with a non-blank instead (e.g. `temp = "x"`).

The final function that works is therefore:

```
string removeWhiteSpace(string current)
{
  string myNewString = "";
  string temp = "x";
  for (char c : current)
  {
    if (temp.back() != ' ' && c == ' ')
    {
      myNewString.push_back(' ');
    }
    temp.push_back(c);
    if (c != ' ')
    {
      myNewString.push_back(c);
    }
  }
  return myNewString;
}
```

Comment: @ponikoli: there were also a few other errors, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want to remove extra whitespaces. This code will help.

```
string removeWhiteSpace(string current)
{
  string myNewString = "";
  string temp = "";
  int l=current.length();
  myNewString+=current[0];
  for(int i=1;i<l;i++){
      if(myNewString[myNewString.length()-1]==' ' && current[i]==' ')
          continue;
      else
          myNewString+=current[i];
  }
  return myNewString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more C++ish solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string str)
{
    bool seen_space = false;
    auto end{ std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                             [&seen_space](unsigned ch) {
                                 bool is_space = std::isspace(ch);
                                 std::swap(seen_space, is_space);
                                 return seen_space && is_space;
                             }
              )
    };

    if (end != str.begin() && std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(end[-1])))
        --end;

    str.erase(end, str.end());
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char const *foo{ "Hello              World!       " };
    std::cout << '\"' << remove_excessive_ws(foo) << "\"\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
"Hello World!"
```